# show ip interface brief in expect script

Tags: telnet, remote-access, expect, cisco

I would like to be able to setup a expect script file that would remote into multiple switches.

Do you know how to write expert script for telnet to 200 switches and run a command example: `show ip interface brief` then list all switch status on Linux??

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet 192.168.0.1
expect "Username:"
send "MyUsername\r"
expect "assword:"
send "MyPassword\r"
send "show ip int br\r"
interact timeout 5
expect {
    "MORE --, next page" {send -- " "; exp_continue}
    "*?2626#*" {send -- "exit \r"}
}
```

***Thanks Dinesh, after my expect script as below:***

## !/usr/bin/expect -f

## Slurp up the input file

set fp [open "input.txt" r]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp
set prompt ">"
log_file -noappend switch_port_status.txt
foreach ip [split $file_data "\n"] {
puts "Switch $ip Interface Status"
spawn telnet $ip
expect "Username:"
send "MyUsername\r"
expect "assword:"
send "MyPassword\r"
expect $prompt
# To avoid sending 'Enter' key on huge configurations
send "show ip int br\r"
expect $prompt
expect {
-ex "--More--" { send -- " "; exp_continue }
"*>" { send "exit\r" }
}
set timeout 1; # Reverting to default timeout
# Sending 'exit' at global level prompt will close the connection
expect eof
}

***Thats workable. But following is the error message i got, how can i fix this? thanks***

switch-hostname>Switch  Interface Status
spawn telnet
usage: telnet [-l user] [-a] host-name [port]
send: spawn id exp9 not open
while executing
"send "MyUsername\r""
("foreach" body line 5)
invoked from within
"foreach ip [split $file_data "\n"] {
puts "Switch $ip Interface Status"
spawn telnet $ip
expect "Username:"
send "MyUsername\r"
expec..."
(file "./autotelnet.sh" line 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a file which inputs the switch IP information in a line by line manner. Using `terminal length 0` will save our work & finally `log_file` comes in handy to save the output.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#Slurp up the input file
set fp [open "input.txt" r]
# To avoid empty lines, 'nonewline' flag is used
set file_data [read -nonewline $fp]
close $fp 
set prompt "#"
log_file -noappend switch_port_status.txt
foreach ip [split $file_data "\n"] {
    puts "Switch $ip Interface Status"
    spawn telnet $ip
    expect "Username:"
    send "MyUsername\r"
    expect "assword:"
    send "MyPassword\r"
    expect $prompt
    # To avoid sending 'Enter' key on huge configurations
    send "terminal length 0\r"
    expect $prompt
    set timeout 120;# Increasing timeout to 2mins, as it may take more time to get the prompt
    send "show ip int br\r"
    expect $prompt
    set timeout 10; # Reverting to default timeout
    # Sending 'exit' at global level prompt will close the connection
    send "exit\r"
    expect eof
}
```

**Note :** The close of connection is handled on the basis of sending `exit` command only. So, make sure, the `exit` command always sent at global level of prompt. Instead of depending on `exit`, we can also use typical way of closing  the telnet connection i.e. 'Ctrl+]' key combination.

```
#This will send 'Ctrl+]' to close the telnet connection gracefully
send "\x1d"
expect "telnet>"
send "quit\r"
expect "Connection"
```

If suppose you want to get multiple commands output, then keep them in a file and send them one by one.

Comment: Thats workable. But I got the above error message as post, how can i fix this? thanks

Comment: @Danny Luk : it looks like telnet session spawned without any ip address at all. i.e. the `ip` variable might be empty. The file may contains empty lines as well.  To avoid this, we can use `nonewline` flag in `read ` command. I have updated my answer. Please check. If this post answers your question, you can accept the answer.